# Magento Get total ordered items' quantity in success page

Tags: php, magento

I have looked whole of the google and could not find a working solution for my requirement. Please help.

I am trying to get total quantity of all the ordered items in success.html. I am able to get order id and subtotal and want total qty of all the items ordered.

I can do this in cart page but not on success page.

Comment: Provide some code, please!

Comment: Dont have any code to share here, all I have is similar to below answer that is used to get individual products.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code,

```
<?php
$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());//increment_id,like 100000004
$ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($ordered_items as $item){
    echo $item->getSku();
    echo "<br />";
    echo $item->getQtyOrdered();
    echo "<br />";
    //ordered qty of item
    echo $item->getName();
    echo "<br />";
    // etc.
} 
?>
```

To get total qty of an order,use below code.

```
$order->getData('total_qty_ordered');
```

Comment: I have tried this, here I get invidiual items list, but i want total quantity of all items ordered, i.e, first item - 2 qty, second item 3 qty, so I want total qty in this order i.e, 5. Thank you for taking time to answer my question

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Cant express happiness that I feel after this.

Comment: Is there any way to do reduce the quantity of ordered items, suppose i have ordered 2 product with different quantities, i want to decrement the same product quantities from the inventory, is it possible?

Comment: @Naveenbos, it automatically gets decremented once you place order